# Column 'Status' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: c#, mysql

i can't seem to solve the problem here... any help?

```
sql.cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM patient_monitoring LEFT JOIN patient_information ON patient_monitoring.PatiendID = patient_information.PatiendID WHERE detoProper >='" + mysqlDateFormatNow + "' AND Status = 'on queue' ORDER BY dateTimeProper", sql.con);
```

Comment: First problem: you shouldn't be building up SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, always. Second problem: you've got a join, and presumably both tables have a Status column. You need to specify which you want. Note that this has nothing to do with C#, and you'd get the same issue if you executed the query directly in a MySQL admin tool.

Comment: is there a `status` field in both tables you are joining on? need to see table schema.

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a column named `status` in both tables. And if you don't specifiy which one you mean, the DB can't do it automatically.

So specify the table name in front like

```
AND patient_monitoring.Status = 'on queue'
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'patient_monitoring.Status = 'on queue' ORDER BY dateTimeProper'
--------
this is the new error BTW Status and dateTimeProper is from patient_monitoring table

Comment: @davz_11 what is in your `mysqlDateFormatNow` variable?

Comment: just the date today that is in mysql date format

Comment: @davz_11: Did you forget something? `SELECT * FROM patient_monitoring LEFT JOIN patient_information ON patient_monitoring.PatiendID = patient_information.PatiendID WHERE detoProper >='" + mysqlDateFormatNow + "' AND patient_monitoring.Status = 'on queue' ORDER BY dateTimeProper`

Comment: @davz_11 ...and as mentioned, it would be better to make `mysqlDateFormatNow` a parameter.   `MySqlParameter mysqlDateParm = new MySqlParameter("@MyDate", MyDate);
cmd.Parameters.Add(mysqlDateParm);
... where detoProper >= @MyDate ...`